# sf::View visibility Check

Tags: view, camera, sfml

Ok, so I've been working on a game with some friends for a school project. We have used SFML.

I've been working lately on the camera and a tile implementations system and now I need them to work together.

The camera works like this:
I have two different sf::View, one for the game world and one for the hud. The one for the game world follows the player in the x-axis.

The tile system works in a way where it reads in a txt file and draw sprites based on the information from the txt file.

As it is now I always draw all the tiles, even if it's outside of the cameras view. Not good. I need a way to check if the tiles are outside of the cameras view before I draw them. How do I do this?

I did find this:
[Get X and Y offset of sf::View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457812/get-x-and-y-offset-of-sfview)

but I can't really wrap my head around how to make this info work in my game.

Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Mvh Elis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out after finding this:
http://fr.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=10590.0